# Regex to remove irrelevant keyvalues - R

Tags: r, regex, key-value

I am trying to build a **regex** that removes all unwanted key values from list. In the below example, I am trying to keep values associated with variables *rev, qty, code* and *zip*. While ignoring the rest (*State, DMA, Source etc.*) from the output:

**Example:**

```
rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987;location=Atlanta
rev=10.60|34;State=New York;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY;
code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268;Source=69752|458
rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254;DMA=TampaBay
State=Florida;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254;rev=3|24|8
```

**Desired Output:**

```
rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987
rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY
code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268
rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254
qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254;rev=3|24|8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a white list and paste the terms together to build a regex for `str_extract_all`:

```
library(tidyverse)

whitelist <- c("rev", "qty", "code", "zip")
regex_pattern <- paste(paste0("(?<=^|;)", whitelist, "\\=.+?(?=;|$)"), collapse = "|")

df %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_extract_all(V1, regex_pattern) %>% map(paste, collapse = ";"))
```

**Output:**

```
                                                   V1
1                     rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987
2        rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY
3                     code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268
4 rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254
5 qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254;rev=3|24|8
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268;Source=69752|458", 
"rev=10.60|34;State=New York;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY;", 
"rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254;DMA=TampaBay", 
"rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987;location=Atlanta", "State=Florida;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254;rev=3|24|8"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This does something looking like you wanted to have.

```
 rev=.*?(;|$)|code=.*?;|qty=.*?;|zip=.*?;
```

assuming, that rev is always the last tag (since it is not terminated with a ; ). Otherwise you have to check all the tags with (;|$) instead.

But you could parse over it as well, which would be more performant - but I guess it has to be RegEx.